# Using P:CommandButton in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Originally I have this form for user input and do a search.

```
         <h:form id="wordForm">
                <h:panelGrid columns="4">

                    <h:inputText id="word" "
                        value="#{wordController.word}" />
                    <h:message for="word" />
                    <h:commandButton id="search" value="search"
                        action="#{wordController.search}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

Now I want to use PrimeFaces for autocomplete feature, and this is my new form with Autocomplete. How can I replace the new form with the above form?

```
   <h:form>
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

            <p:autoComplete id="wordForm" value="#{autoCompleteView.query}"
                completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeQuery}" var="query"
                itemLabel="#{query.displayName}" itemValue="#{query}"
                converter="queryConverter" forceSelection="true" />

            <p:commandButton value="search" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" **action="#{wordController.search}"** />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

More specifically, I think I still need to somehow use "action="#{wordController.search}" in P:CommandAction button so that I don't need to change anything else in backend. But How do I pass the query parameter to the "wordController.word" variable? Because now "action="#autoCompleteView.query" takes the user input.

How can I modify this without significant change to current bean code? Do I have to unify the original search bean WordController with the new AutocompleteView bean? because now the user input is accepted into AutoCompleteView bean.

AutoCompleteView.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class AutoCompleteView {

    private Query query;

    @ManagedProperty("#{queryService}")
    private QueryService service;

    private List<Query> selectedQueries;

    public List<Query> completeQuery(String query) {

        System.out.println(query);
        List<Query> allQueries = service.getQueries();
        List<Query> filteredQueries = new ArrayList<Query>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allQueries.size(); i++) {
            Query skin = allQueries.get(i);
            if(skin.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                filteredQueries.add(skin);
            }
        }

        return filteredQueries;
    }

    public void onItemSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Item Selected", event.getObject().toString()));
    }


    public Query getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public void setService(QueryService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public List<Query> getSelectedQueries() {
        return selectedQueries;
    }

    public void setSelectedQueries(List<Query> selectedQueries) {
        this.selectedQueries = selectedQueries;
    }
}
```

Edited per suggestion:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class WordController {

    private String word;

    // For AutoComplete suggestions
    private Query selectedQuery;

    @Inject
    private QueryService service;

    @Inject
    private Word wordObject;

    public void search() {
        if (word != null && !word.isEmpty()) {
            wordObject.searchWord(word);;
             ...
        }else {
            System.out.println("Query can't be null!");
        } 
    }

    public List<Query> completeQuery(String query) {

        List<Query> allQueries = service.getQueries();
        List<Query> filteredQueries = new ArrayList<Query>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allQueries.size(); i++) {
            Query skin = allQueries.get(i);
            if(skin.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                filteredQueries.add(skin);
            }
        }

        return filteredQueries;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

   public Query getSelectedQuery() {

        return selectedQuery;
    }

    public void setSelectedQuery(Query selectedQuery) {
        this.selectedQuery = selectedQuery;
    }
}
```

Question: Originally, my 'word' is filled through an "h:inputText" in JSF view and search() is called in JSF:

```
<h:commandButton id="search" value="Search!" action="#{wordController.search}" />
```

Now, how do I get "selectedQuery" from completeQuery() method, and then use it to fill "word" and then call search() method?

Comment: Why you separate your autocomplete method in a different controller? It could be inside your `wordController` and you could just use your `wordController.word` as value so your search method would already have the filled attribute (I assume word) to search

Comment: Yes. that was my thinking too.  I will try to consolidate the two together. Thank you.

Comment: If you are thinking on reuse it to another controller you could make it so in and abstract class with an abstract getter method so the inherited class would implement and inside it you call your autocomplete with this method. I hope you have understand it. Your wordController then would extends this abstractClass

Comment: The completeQuery(String query) takes an parameter, but in xhtml, the way to call is parameterless, "completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeQuery}". I was following the demo. How is the parameter passed and why does the signature of completeQuery() need a parameter?

Comment: This would not change at all the method still needs the parameter and you still use it. It needs a parameter because it was designed that way. I suppose that it would not be possible to guess for which parameter you would bind it to (if it there was not a parameter) most important for which type so they force you to have a string on it. They could add another attribute, to use the same as value would not be wise since it is the return value.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, it's still not clear to me how to make this possible. Let's say I just use WordController class, and I modified it.

Comment: Your title is btw not very good (~bad). You cannot use a `p:commandButton` outside PrimeFaces (assuming the p prefix points to the PrimeFaces namespace), so the title does not have any meaning or provide info. Please correct it.